# JavaScript event object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, dom-events

I want to transfer all information of an event to a server. To do so I would need to serialize the event.

This is what I tried:

```
var element = document.QuerySelector('div');
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
}, false);
```

But all I get is an empty dictionary: `{}`

Is there any way to serialize an event object in a cross browser manner?

Comment: create your own object using the properties you want from the event (don't reference the DOM) then serialise that

Comment: Thanks, @MihaiDinculescu: I didn't find it. Gonna close this one, then